# In Android how to decode a jpeg in cmyk color format?

Tags: android, cmyk, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to decode a jpeg that is in CMYK color format. BitmapFactory returns null. I googled around but with no luck. Is it possibile Android team did not the right job supporting all kind of color format?

I'm using Android 2.2.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: loading the JPEG using the external library [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/) compiled with NDK. It has been a hard work, but I did it!

Comment: Would you post some code showing how you did it? Then other users will benefit.

Comment: Since it's a mixture of Java and C it would be better if I could show the entire project. Where could I upload it in a safe manner? I mean, in order to make it available for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible I'd say:

http://code.google.com/p/skia/issues/detail?id=69

Comment: Status of that issue is set to as new. It means it was not corrected, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, so you're not likely so see any change soon. Isn't fixed on 2.3.6 at least.

Comment: do you know other solutions? other libs for reading jpeg compatible with Android?

Comment: Porting/building lcms in Android shouldn't be impossible (but not trivial). http://www.littlecms.com/

Comment: I used libjpeg compiled with NDK :)