# Android Universal Image Loader Custom Image Decoder with CMYK support

Tags: android, image-processing, universal-image-loader

**Background**

We have just swapped to the UIL library, which seems fantastic. Unfortunately we have to support CMYK images (against our will) and have attempted to modify an existing `ImageDecoder` called `BaseImageDecoder`.

The code for this can be found here. http://pastebin.com/NqbSr0w3

We had an existing AsyncTask http://pastebin.com/5aq6QrRd that used an ImageMagick wrapper described in this SO post ([Convert Image byte[] from CMYK to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074315/convert-image-byte-from-cmyk-to-rgb)). This worked fine before in our setup.

**The Problem**

The current decoder fails to load the cached image from the file system and this results in a decoding error. We have looked through the source code and believe we are using the right functions. We also thought that adding our extra level of decoding at this point in the process was ideal, as the image may have been resized and stored on the file system.

```
File cachedImageFile = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(decodingInfo.getImageUri());
                    if (!cachedImageFile.exists()) {
                        Log.v("App", "FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
                        return null;
                    }
```

The above lines always return that the file does not exist.

**The Question**

Are we incorrect to process our CMYK images at this point, and if not why can't we get the image from the cache on file system?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted in under 30 seconds of posting? Someone could not possibly have read the entire question properly in that time frame, espeically without any comments?

Comment: Did you enable caching on disc? Please show your configuration and display options.